# error: no matching function for call to 'sort'. How can I do this that will make all compilers happy?

Tags: c++

I am working in a class file called room.cpp and I created functions outside of the function called from room.h.

I'm trying to use sort like so:

```
std::sort(roomLinesSort.begin(), roomLinesSort.end(), time);
```

The code compiles and works perfectly fine in my clang compiler but I'm getting this: error: no matching function for call to 'sort' when I compile on my school's provided compiler online.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated:)

```
bool time(std::string a, std::string b);

bool amVsPm(std::string a, std::string b);

bool week(std::string a, std::string b);

void Room :: roomString(std::string & file, std::string givenRoom){

//my sort code is here.
```

It works fine in both compilers if I set them as lambda functions but I'm not allowed to use "auto" for this assignment.

Comment: Are you using `using namespace std;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard library there is `time` function (in `ctime` header). It looks like the compiler see both functions, one provided by you, and next one from `ctime` header, and there is ambiguity which function should be called.

You can change the name of your sort function from `time` to *someNameDifferentThanTime*. Or you can cast `time` while calling sort:

```
std::sort(roomLinesSort.begin(), roomLinesSort.end(), static_cast<bool(*)(string,string)>(time));
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer of rafix07 for why things are going wrong. The fix will work, however, I wouldn't accept it in code review if you use the cast.

Instead, I would request you to rename the method to something like `lessThanByTime` as it would improve readability. Especially if you also need an equal method. For example:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), lessThanByTime);
auto newEnd = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), equalByTime);
//...
```